# C-Preprocessor and Implementing a string table in low memory

Tags: c, string, storage, c-preprocessor

I have some pre-processor definitions that make storing UI text easy in a single array (see below).  Also makes supporting other languages less cumbersome.

```
#define DECLARE_STRING_ENUM_FST(name, value) name
#define DECLARE_STRING_ENUM_SND(name, value) value
#define DECLARE_STRING_ENUM(name, macro) \
    typedef enum name { macro(DECLARE_STRING_ENUM_FST) } name; \
    static const char* name##_sztable[] = { macro(DECLARE_STRING_ENUM_SND) }; \

// this is a string table usage 
#define MSG_ENUM_(X) \
    X(STR_ONE, "One"), \
    X(STR_TWO, "Two"), \
    X(STR_THREE, "Three"), \
    X(STR_PRESS_ENTER, "Press Enter")

// the actual declaration is here
DECLARE_STRING_ENUM(menu, MSG_ENUM_)
```

the result is an array of strings and an enum representing indexes in the array.

However, since it is an array of pointers to constant char*, it takes up ram which is very scarce on this device. The couple of large string tables in the program are taking up ~30% of the available RAM.  so this can't be ignored.

Dependency of RAM would go to zero if the enum values were starting positions of the null-terminated sub-strings in one large const char string stored in code space.

i.e:

```
menu_sztable[] = "One\0Two\0Three\0Press Enter\0";
STR_ONE -> 0
STR_TWO -> 4
STR_Three -> 8
STR_PressEnter -> 14
```

Is there a clever way to use the C-Preprocessor to make this? I'd like to avoid building up the enum manually or having to to write a pre-build command program that converts the arrays.

Comment: Isn't this more or less what the compiler does for you with all string literals?

Comment: The strings could be embedded into a packed struct and the enums taken with offsetof directive. It's then a linker issue to put the struct to .text segment.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen can you provide an example? That sounds promising.

Comment: For easily automating things like this, why try to make due with the C preprocessor?  Write a simple python script that generates your perfectly efficient C code.  That's easy, clean, easily translated across languages.  Just add your python script as a step in your build process.

Comment: Have you tried `static const char* const name##_sztable[] = /* ... */` which should put the array of pointers into ROM with most embedded device tool chains (assuming that ROM/flash space isn't an issue as well)?

Comment: @MichaelBurr bingo! That extra const did it.  Would you post an answer please with your elegant one word solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make your array of pointers `const` most (all?) tool chains will place that array into ROM/flash which usually has less of an issue with space:

```
static const char* const name##_sztable[] = /* ... */
//                 ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a full solution, maybe a halfway ...

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
static struct foo {
    char arr0[5];
    char arr1[4];
    char arr2[4];
} tmp = { "Zero","One","Two"};
enum {
   ARR0 = offsetof(struct foo, arr0),
   ARR1 = offsetof(struct foo, arr1),
   ARR2 = offsetof(struct foo, arr2)
};

int main()
{
      printf("%d %d %d\n",ARR0,ARR1,ARR2);
      return 0;
}
```

Can't remember the linker option, but when disassembling this, I'll get:

```
    .file   "tst.c"
    .data     // manually replace with .text
_tmp:
    .ascii "Zero\0"
    .ascii "One\0"
    .ascii "Two\0"  // manually insert .data here, recompile and run...
    .def    ___main;        .scl    2;      .type   32;     .endef
```

Comment: thanks.  It's a start. Perhaps I could use the sizeof for the array sizes and preprocessor to spit this section out.  I should be able to force .readonly with the const keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You could first define a whole bunch of compile time constants that will hold the postion of your strings, something like

```
#define DEFINE_LENGTH(NAME, STR) NAME ## _POS,       \
      NAME ## _DUMMY = (NAME ## _POS + sizeof(STR))
```

inside the declaration of an enumeration

```
enum {
  ... your macro expansion goes here ...
};
```

Then you create a long string by concatenating

```
#define DEFINE_COMPONENT(NAME, STR) STR "\0"
```

inside the initialization of the long string

```
char const table[] = ... your macro expansion goes here ...;
```

Now your string pointers are are obtained with

```
#define DEFINE_VARIABLE(NAME, STR) *const NAME = &table[NAME ## _POS]
```

inside the following setting:

```
char const  ... your macro expansion goes here ...;
```

(maybe there are still some syntax errors here and there but I hope you get the picture.)

All that would be simpler if you'd use a macro meta-package such as boost or P99.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do:

```
#if ENGLISH
#define STR_ONE "one"
#define STR_TWO "two"
...
#elif SPANISH
#define STR_ONE "uno"
#define STR_TWO "dos"
...
#endif
```

Is there a reason why you need offsets and not string pointers themselves?

Comment: Yes, lists.  e.g. as slow medium fast, or January, February, etc.   You can index jump to the right string.